# System.Net.WebException:

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, webservice-client

I have created a Windows application for my project. I am utilizing an external party's WEB SERVICE in my Windows application. Whenever I click a button, the web service client gets created button click event and then particular method of web service is invoked.

Now, I am facing a Timeout exception when invoking the method of web service all the time. I have contacted the web service provider but they are saying that it is working fine on their end. Also the wsdl file is opening in all the browsers perfectly but in the application it is not giving the response.

Response/ Error Message System.Net.WebException:

> The operation has timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at WebServiceStudio.WSSWebRequest.GetResponse()

I have tested this web service using Webservice test client, SOAP UI also, but I am not getting any response.

I tried increasing the timeout in my Windows application by writing the following code:

```
// Creating the Client
 MoreMoneyBranchListService.Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapPortClient client = new MoreMoneyBranchListService.Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapPortClient();

// Increasing the time out
cl.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 55);
```

Client config:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="moresistemas.com:5005//aws_api_brancheslist.aspx" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapBinding" 
              contract="MoreMoneyBranchListService.Ws_Api_BranchesListSoap‌​Port" 
              name="Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapPort" />
</client>
```

After increasing the timeout, now I am getting the Communication Exception.

Kindly help !!

Comment: Could you please add the error message and your client config file if possible?

Comment: Response/ Error Message

System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at WebServiceStudio.WSSWebRequest.GetResponse()





App.Config File :

<Client>

<endpoint address="http://www.moresistemas.com:5005//aws_api_brancheslist.aspx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapBinding"
                contract="MoreMoneyBranchListService.Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapPort"
                name="Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapPort" />                    
        </client>

Comment: There's obviously something wrong with the service address. First of all it's missing a scheme (`http://` or `https://`). Then, there's a double slash (`//`) right after the port. And it's referring to a `.aspx` resource. Web-services in .NET (ASMX or WCF) usually have `.asmx` or `.svc` endings. So you should check the address.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `receiveTimeout` property in the binding configuration `'Ws_Api_BranchesListSoapPort'` in your config file?

Comment: see this is the same link which I am using to get the WSDL file in Web service CLIENT and it is successfully loading.

LINK : https://www.moresistemas.com:5005/aWs_Api_BranchesList.aspx?wsdl

I changed .aspx to .asmx abd after that it is not loading any file in client.

Also I removed the double slash (//) and kept only one slash (/) but still it is giving me the timeout exception.